# How can return previous page using django class view

Tags: django

with my code, I can create tempfriend in 3 different page. so I'd like to make when I create tempfriend, I hope return previous page. how can I achieve it?

When I use form_valid, there is no request, so `request.META` doesn't work. and if I use self.request, it create tempfriend and just return create page.

```
class tempfriend_create(FormView):
    form_class = forms.CreateTempfriendForm
    template_name = "tempfriends/create.html"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        tempfriend = form.save()
        form.instance.belongs_to = self.request.user
        tempfriend.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER', '/'))
```

Comment: Is there a `self.` missing in your redirect?